# Inno Setup: How to dynamically add files to the installation?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, istool

Is there a way to dynamically fill the `[Dirs]` and `[Files]` sections of an Inno Setup script?

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. during the install process, the user will select *foo* (*foo* matches a repository to get from our SCM)
2. Setup will run a batch to checkout *foo* from our SCM
3. then the content of *foo* must be added to the `[Dirs]` and `[Files]` sections of the script

Everything works fine except for the last step. I searched around and couldn't find explanations on how to do this. I have the feeling that my script should embed all the repositories of our SCM to then be able to copy only the selected ones to the destination directory.

Thanks for your help!

Regards,

Comment: Why do you need to use `[Files]`?  Why not just check out or export the files directly into their intended destination?  (An installer seems overkill for this sort of thing; for example, uninstall support will probably not function correctly if the folder is still an SCM working copy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Inno Setup Prompt for external file location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40984529/850848).

And add the [`recursesubdirs` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=recursesubdirs).

You may also need the [`createallsubdirs` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=createallsubdirs) (assuming from your reference to the `[Dirs]` section).

```
[Files]
Source: "{code:GetScmPath}"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: external recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

```pascal
[Code]

function GetScmPath(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := { make it return path to the checked out files }
end;
```