# Add screen to installation process with InnoSetup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, installshield, inno-setup-v6

I used InstallShield to create installations until now, but I no longer have license for it, therefore I looked for a free alternative and found InnoSetup.

I wrote an .iss file script based on a template I found, but I wasn't able to find a way to do some functionality that I had with InstallShield - when the user runs the installation, one of the screens he gets contains the option to browse the computer and choose a configuration file.

Is it possible to this with InnoSetup? and if it is, I'll be happy if someone can share a code example of how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: You can add such a page using the `CreateInputFilePage` support function. See the `AllPagesExample.iss` sample file in the `Examples` directory in the Inno Setup installation directory for an example.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/40984529/850848

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you are not skilled enough to write the code manually, see the Inno Setup Third-Party Files https://jrsoftware.org/is3rdparty.php where is an easy-to-use GUI which helps you design custom forms.